# C# Ibex DashBoard Bot Framework Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, dashboard, azure-application-insights

I tired Integrating Ibex DashBoard for my bot using BotBuilder Instrumentation package. I have some doubts in config.

We have some events like "MBFEvent.StartTransaction" and "MBFEvent.EndTransaction" which is never used in Instrumentation package. What does this two events mean? . If i understand the meaning i can log it manually.

Also what does "MBFEvent.GoalEvent" does? . If anybody has incorporated all these setting . Please help, their GitHUB page seems dead.

Comment: `what does "MBFEvent.GoalEvent" does?` "MBFEvent.GoalEvent" seems indicate  [GoalTriggeredEvent](https://github.com/Azure/botbuilder-instrumentation/blob/55790d04a6e14e38ba37d17a9708ad640a89d5a2/src/events.ts#L112). Besides, I checked [botbuilder-instrumentation](https://github.com/Azure/botbuilder-instrumentation/search?q=MBFEvent&unscoped_q=MBFEvent) in github, but can not find any documentation/comments for  "MBFEvent.StartTransaction" and "MBFEvent.EndTransaction", if possible, you can [create an issue](https://github.com/Azure/botbuilder-instrumentation/issues) for it.

Comment: What is the use of logging this GoalTriggeredEvent. ? Any data can we extract from this?

Comment: GoalEvents and StartTransaction/EndTransaction appear to be related to how things are displayed in the ibex-dashboard.  There are some comments here: https://github.com/Azure/ibex-dashboard/blob/master/server/dashboards/preconfigured/bot-framework-goals.ts about how goals are displayed.

Comment: @EricDahlvang My bot uses Luis and Qna , at what place should i log StartTransaction/EndTransaction and GoalEvents?